# WatiN - Waiting for Cookies

Tags: c#, browser, cookies, watin, wait

I have been assigned to create a 'kind of' web creeper. The tasks is to go on certain websites, enter a piece of data then submit that data to receive a result.

I have found WatiN to be a great tool at getting this data as it's open source and has all the functionality I need - even if this is misuse of a Testing API (Is it misuse?).

Anyway - What the real question is, is that the

`Browser.WaitForComplete();`

Does not wait for EVERYTHING to load. It seems it just waits for the last `body` tag then returns. However I believe the cookie is not generated when the page is finished loading as it's being generated by an ASP.NET back end - it seems to load after an interactive object which looks like AJAX or something along them lines.

I do not own or host the web site therefore can only gather information based on what I see from the browser and other tools at my disposal.

Is there any way to get WatiN to wait for the cookie to be updated?

Thanks in advanced.

John.

Edit:

As an example of what I'm doing to fix the issue at the minute (Which is a bit unorthodox but it's fixing it for the minute).

`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`
`Browser.WaitForComplete();`

`var cookie = Browser.Eval("document.cookie");`

Now you may understand why I want to find a real solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure could capture an event for this, as I suspect there must be javascript running on the page that ultimately updates the cookie.

If you can tell the difference between an "old" and "updated" cookie, you could try something like this:

```
// Maximum number of loops, to avoid infinite loops
int maxLoops = 10;

// Wait for the page to complete
Browser.WaitForComplete();

// Grab a copy of the current cookie
var cookie = Browser.Eval("document.cookie");

// HACK: Dirty hack to wait for cookie to be updated
while (CookieIsNotUpdated(cookie) && i++ <= maxLoops)
{
    Browser.WaitForComplete(); // (Or other wait/sleep)
    cookie = Browser.Eval("document.cookie");
}
```

This isn't a nice way of doing it, but it should work in the absence of anything better.

Comment: Indeed this was one way I had it originally.

However I found that even clearing the cookies before the page would load was in vain as the page seems to generate a cookie template for example:

'cookieData=6&cookieData2=6'

then it seems to change them after the cookie has been created.

'cookieData=4&cookieData2=1'

I'm hopeful that there are some more accurate ways thank this. Thank you for the feedback however it is much appreciated!

Comment: If there is no way you can tell if the cookie is "updated", then the best you can do is decide how long you're prepared to wait, and then wait that long. It won't be reliable, but I can't see any other way.

Comment: That said - if you poke around in the page you're calling, you may be able to inject some javascript and notify you when it's "done", depending on how it works

Comment: As you have said. Injecting Javascript is the solution I think I will be looking into. I'm sure there is some kind of Javascript functionality to tell me when the cookie has been created & when it's ready.